# Floating child div to fill only remaining space

Tags: html, css

I want that yellow box to fill all the available space both vertically and horizontally without overlaying the picture.

(I'm trying to do it without using table properties)

Any ideas?

This is how it looks now:

[image: This is how it looks now]

and this is what i want:

[image: and this is what i want]

```css
.content-block-body{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
    overflow:auto;
}
.content-block-text{
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
    padding:2%; 
}
.content-block-image{
    background-color: greenyellow;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-block-body">
  <div class="content-block-text">
    <div>月額固定と成果報酬が選べます</div>
    <div>成果報酬額に上限おもうけられます</div>
    <div>料金が明瞭で予算に合わせた対策が可能</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-block-image"> <img src="image-1.jpg"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is position:absolute; out of the question? edit: never mind, the thing I was thinking about won't help you with this.

Comment: your snippet is a bit different from your screenshots...

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not `display: table` and `display: table-cell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `float: left` makes the yellow area not "stretch." To make the image float to the right of the text, it has to come before the text. So we change the order of the content blocks:

```
<div class="content-block-body">
  <div class="content-block-image"> <img src="image-1.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="content-block-text">
    <div>月額固定と成果報酬が選べます</div>
    <div>成果報酬額に上限おもうけられます</div>
    <div>料金が明瞭で予算に合わせた対策が可能</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then adjust the css:

```
.content-block-body {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
    overflow:auto;
}
.content-block-text{
    /*float:left;*/ /* this we remove */
    background-color: red;
    padding:2%; 
    /* this we add: */
    overflow: auto;
}
.content-block-image{
    background-color: greenyellow;
    float: right;
}
```

Note that whenever you float things you'll most likely need to add what's called a "clearfix". In this case, apply the clearfix to the `.content-block-body` to make it extend vertically to fit the floated element http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `float: left` is the reason your yellow area isn't filling the whole width isn't filling the whole space.

Comment: @henry and so we are going to change our markup everytime this happens? hmmm OK

Comment: As always, there is more than one way to the target. In a perfect world HTML and CSS would be completely decoupled but in this, depending on graphic design, they need sometimes to adjust to each other. The trick with floating only one element and setting `overflow: auto` to other works in many browsers, does not use flex which has 4 different syntaxes, and doesn’t use table properties which author wanted to avoid. One has to decide what to trade for what.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify width of left block and right block in CSS and make image width 100%

```css
.content-block-body{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
    overflow:auto;
}
.content-block-text{
    float:left;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding:2%;
    width:56%;
}
.content-block-image{
    background-color: greenyellow;
    float: right;
    min-width:200px;
    width:40%;
}
.content-block-image img{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-block-body">
  <div class="content-block-text">
    <div>月額固定と成果報酬が選べます</div>
    <div>成果報酬額に上限おもうけられます</div>
    <div>料金が明瞭で予算に合わせた対策が可能</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-block-image"> <img src="image-1.jpg"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 flex. That's the only thing that works just fine when it comes to getting the height of the parent node for child node. All the hacks for old browsers doesn't work always.

```css
.content-block-body{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: brown;
    overflow:auto;
    display: flex;
    clear: both;
}
.content-block-text{
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.content-block-image{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.content-block-image img{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-block-body">
  <div class="content-block-text">
    <div>月額固定と成果報酬が選べます</div>
    <div>成果報酬額に上限おもうけられます</div>
    <div>料金が明瞭で予算に合わせた対策が可能</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-block-image"> 
    <img src="//placehold.it/250x250">
  </div>
</div>
```

also check out this cool site for code snippets on [centering in css](http://howtocenterincss.com/).